# mysql udf c function memory issue

Tags: mysql, c, function, plugins, user-defined-functions

the following test code generates incorrect output when run on a query that returns more than one record

```
my_bool helloworld_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
    if (args->arg_count != 1 || args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT) {
        strcpy(message, "helloworld() requires one string argument");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

char *helloworld(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *error) {
    char *str = args->args[0];
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *ptr = malloc(len + 1);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        strcpy(error, "helloworld: failed to allocate memory");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ptr[i] = str[i];
    }
    ptr[len] = '\0';
    *length = len;
    return ptr;
}

void helloworld_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid) {
    free(initid->ptr);
}
```

```
MariaDB [test]> select helloworld(name) from users;
+------------------+
| helloworld(name) |
+------------------+
| john             |
| paul             |
| george           |
| ringoe           |
+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

why ringoe instead of ringo?

I tried different ways to clean up the memory, but the result doesn't change
How do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which function is ran when there when you say ```select helloworld(name) from users```?

Comment: The 'e' is coming from 'george' it's because your memory cleanup code is incorrect.

Comment: ```for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ptr[i] = str[i];
    }
    ptr[len] = '\0'```  <---- Is that a string copy? Doesn't C provide a ```strcpy``` function?

Comment: I defined the function to be executed like this: CREATE FUNCTION helloworld RETURNS STRING SONAME 'helloworld.so'; I know the 'e' is from the previous value but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @Haris c provides many functions. That For loop is just a test